# Spring MVC IndexOutOfBounds under load

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring MVC application with a REST-like web service. When I load-test this app - from time to time it throws the following exception. I don't know why this could happen, but it happens only during load-test - therefore under load.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0    
    java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
    java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$RequestMappingInfo.bestMatchedPattern(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:1017)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodResolver.resolveHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:613)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:422)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:415)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:788)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

What could be the reason for this kind of an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug ([SPR-7525](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7525)), fixed in Spring 3.0.5.